# I want to insert data in <Pre> tag using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automation

[enter image description here][1] I am not able to insert any data in  tag. I always show Element is not reachable through Keyboard.
It is possible through Javascript to insert. PLS help......XPath is not working. I am adding the to rectify.
                                   **OR**
If this is not problem of  then how to inert data in provided field.

**[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk74u.png**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following code will solve your problem

```
By preTagXpath = By.xpath("//pre");
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        String preValue = "This should be the new value";
        js.executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerText='" + preValue + "';");
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(preTagXpath).getText());
```

Comment: JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) w;
        String preValue = "This should be the new value";
        js.executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerText='" + preValue + "';");

Comment: but still not inserting any data in field. I am not able to insert any query in field.

Comment: 1. First check is above XPath pointing to correct web element?
2. Share your whole web page. May be there is more than one pre tag on page
3. Is your pre tag is in the current viewport?

Comment: Yes <Pre> tag is also returning the get text in console, but not inserting any value

Comment: 3. Is your pre tag is in the current viewport?

Comment: It's working after change the  js.executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[1].innerText='" + preValue + "';");